# Change of colors in Drop down not working on iPad,  works on everything else

Tags: html, css, macos, ipad, drop-down-menu

Change of colors in Drop down not working on ipad
works on everything else

to test this
[Drop down test link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option)

Use this:
`<select>
      <option style="color: rgb(0,187,0);">Volvo</option>
      <option style="color: rgb(0,187,0);" >Saab</option>
      <option>Mercedes</option>
      <option>Audi</option>
 </select>`

This works on Linux and windows. The color of Volvo and Sab dropdown will be green on windows pc and linux.

Not working on ipad... Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: This doesnt work on IPAD...  please use the w3c school test link on ipad.. make changes to test the answer.

Comment: Combo box didnt work JQuery version 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Generally people who work on the web prefer hex values (i.e. #ffffff for white), but if you need it in this format, you could try rgba values instead. The "a" adds the alpha channel, the other values are otherwise the same. E.g. rgba(0,187,0,1).

"1" is 100% alpha, whereas "0.2" is be 20% alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Not much you can do it seems. iPad's browser is using its own styling for the select list, ignoring your coloring. If it's too important for your site you could try using one of those jquery combo-box plugins like http://do-web.com/jdropdown/overview (requires jquery library)

Comment: Combo box solution didnt work sir.. do you suggest any other alternative?